# Server reporting Error 404 on click of menu

Tags: impresspages

I think I'm having a server configuration error but not sure. Can someone figure this out:

Link: http://isaweb.co/rbobois/

On click on the pages in the menu, the server report an error 404. This is so for all pages except the main homepage.

The server, in fact, do not find the folder as pointed in the URL.

Can Impresspages solve this issue?

If it is a server error, what should I ask my hosting company?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that your server doesn't support `.htaccess` file configuration or something is wrong with it. Maybe you forgot to upload it to a server. Or the server ignores it.